get optionset value using powerautomate flow in D365
I have tried steps the given in the below blog, some how I am not getting output properly.
https://community.dynamics.com/blogs/post/?postid=8893c954-371f-47d5-8b04-70eec43d90fd#:~:text=We%20can%20retrieve%20the%20Option,base%2Durl%20and%20click%20Signin.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and read [ask].

When I added open [ bracket additionally to the start and in the end ] bracket into json values and put into schema field it is worked as expected.
https://community.dynamics.com/blogs/post/?postid=8893c954-371f-47d5-8b04-70eec43d90fd#:%7E:text=We%20can%20retrieve%20the%20Option,base%2Durl%20and%20click%20Signin
refer screen shot belowenter image description hereenter image description here
